# Passing parameters to Vuex getters from a Vuex action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a Vuex getter that I call from various components in my application. However, I have found a case were slightly more complex logic is required before calling the getter, so I am making use of a Vuex Action. How can I call the getter function with a parameter from my action?

I use constants for naming getters/mutations/actions, so my getter is defined as follows: `[GETTER_NAME]: state => param => { return {/.../} }`. In my Vuex action, I would like to call the getter as follows `getters[GETTER_NAME](someParam)`. However, this does not seem to work (even though `getters[GETTER_NAME]` returns a function).

Calling the getter from a component works perfectly fine. I simply create `computed` function and use `...mapGetters({getterName: GETTER_NAME})`. To call the getter with a parameter I just say `getterName(someParam)`.

```
[GETTER_NAME]: state => param=> {
    return {/.../}
},

[ACTION_NAME]: (context, param) => {
    getters[GETTER_NAME](param)
      ? context.commit(MUTATION_X, param)
      : context.commit(MUTATION_Y, param);
}
```

The getter gets called, however, it returns the function without passing in the parameter. Am I doing something wrong or am I misunderstanding the way getters work in Vuex?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call like `context.getters[GETTER_NAME](someParam)` inside `actions` here.

```js
[GETTER_NAME]: state => param=> {
return {/.../}
},

[ACTION_NAME]: (context, param) => {
   context.getters[GETTER_NAME](param)
     ? context.commit(MUTATION_X, param)
     : context.commit(MUTATION_Y, param);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In actions have injected parameters : `dispatch`, `commit`, `getters` and `rootState`. Therefore you can access getters like this:

```
ACTION_NAME: ({ commit, getters }, payload) => {
    let MY_VARIABLE = getters.GETTER_NAME(payload)
    console.log(MY_VARIABLE)
}
```

This works fine even if you try to access a getter from a different module.
Though you can use getters with context via `context.getters` the syntax gets a bit longish inside the action when using it this way.